# NodeJS send picture to webpage

Tags: node.js, express

Id like to get pictures from a nodejs express-server to show on my webpage. I have a relative path to the file on the server. This path also includes subfolder.

```
 <img src="pictures/?path=rel_path"/>
```

On the serverside I tried this:

```
app.get('/pictures', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + res.query.path);
});
```

I get this error:

```
Error: ENOENT, stat d:\...\src.\rel_path        // where comes src. from?
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, because the file cannot be found.
Is this necessary at all, or is there a better way to send the files to the webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To serve any static content from your server (either images or other files) you can place this code in your app.js file

```
// static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

No need to define route for this.

Comment: I have added this. What would the link in the <img>-tag be, I have subfolders where the images are located?

Comment: For instance, If you have an image "/public/images/test.jpg" then <img src="images/test.jpg">

Comment: Is there a way to make it that easy with video and audio -files?

Comment: Any file in your public directory is accessible and will be served directly.So you can define the path of audio and video file same as you have defined for images

Comment: Using the src for video file causes this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Oh, it works if I don't use dynamic generated src-addresses. Seems to be a problem with angular-js